# Statically linking matio library using g++

Tags: c++, static-linking, matio

How do you statically link [matio](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matio/), a library for reading mat-files, mainly used by matlab and octave into an executable?

If the file *main.cpp* holds matio functionality the compiler call

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -Imatio/include matio/lib/libmatio.a
```

fails with a bunch of error messages like: *undefined reference to `inflateEnd'*. This can be resolved by also adding zlib to the compiler call:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -Imatio/include matio/lib/libmatio.a -lz
```

Now the error messages differ with something like *undefined reference to `__intel_sse2_strlen'*. So it appears that the zlib library is necessary for the comilation.

I now have the following questions:

1. What do you need to do to statically link the matio library in an executable?
2. Why do I need to add the zlib library even though I configured and compiled matio with *./configure --without-libz*?

Comment: Did you build matio with g++ or some other compiler?

Comment: @tsnorri I use configure and make to build matio. Apparently it uses icc to build its libraries...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build matio without zlib you apparently need to invoke configure with

```
./configure --with-zlib=no
```

(Checked this from `configure.ac` and `config/matio_zlib.m4`.)

In case you want to build matio with icc, Intel's [developer pages](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/unresolved-external-symbol-_intel_sse2_strlen) tell that *__intel_sse2_strlen* is defined in libirc.a on Linux and libirc.lib on Windows.

To compile matio with the gcc do

```
./configure --with-zlib=no CC=gcc
```

afterwards, the matio library is statically linkable with the call posted in the question